# Bluemix上のpythonプログラムから、e-mailを発信したいんですが・・・

Tags: python, sendmail, bluemix

Bluemix上のPyyhon実行環境から、e-mailを発信したいんですが、mailコマンドとか、sendmail
コマンドが見つからなくて困ってます。どうすればいいですか？教えてください。

Answer (score 1):

残念ながらLinux boxのsendmailは使えませんね。

BluemixのサービスカタログにあるSendGridではいかがでしょうか。
Free Packageプランでもかなり使えそうです。
Pythonのサンプルコードは下記URLをご参照ください。

https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Code_Examples/python.html